# How to skip webpages during a web scraping in rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to collect information using rvest package in R.
While collecting the data with for loop, I found some of the pages do not contain information so that it comes out an error: Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.

Here is my R code. The page number 15138 and 15140 do have information, whereas 15139 does not. How can I skip 15139 with for loop function?

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)



source_url <- "https://go2senkyo.com/local/senkyo/"
senkyo <- data.frame() 
for (i in 15138:15140) { 
Sys.sleep(0.5) 
target_page <- paste0(source_url, i)
recall_html <- read_html(target_page, encoding = "UTF-8")


prefecture <- recall_html %>%
        html_nodes(xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "column_ttl_small", " " ))]') %>%
        html_text()

city <- recall_html %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "column_ttl", " " ))]') %>%
    html_text()
city <- trimws(gsub("[\r\n]", "", city )) 



senkyo2 <- cbind(prefecture, city) 
senkyo  <- rbind(senkyo , senkyo2) 

}
```

I'm looking forward to your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle exceptions a few different ways. I'm a `noob` when it comes to scraping, but here are a few options for your situation.

#### Tailor Your Loop Range

If you know that you don't want the value `15139`, you can remove from the vector of options, like:

```
for (i in c(15138,15140)) {
```

Which will completely ignore `1539` when running your loop.

#### Add Control Flow

This is basically the same thing as tailoring your loop range, but handles the exception within the loop itself, like:

```
for (i in 15138:15140) { 
Sys.sleep(0.5)
# control statement
if (i == 15139 {
  next # moves to next iteration of loop, in this case 15140
 }
target_page <- paste0(source_url, i) # not run if i == 15139, since loop skipped to next iteration
```

#### Condition Handling Tools

This is where I get out of my depth, and constantly reference [Advanced-R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html). Essentially, you can wrap functions like `try()` around your potentially buggy code, which can insulate your loop from errors and keep it from breaking, and gives you flexibility about what to do if your code breaks in specific ways.

My usual approach would be to add something to your code like:

```
# wrap the part of your code that can break in try() 
recall_html <- try(read_html(target_page, encoding = "UTF-8")) 
# you'll still see your error, but it won't stop your code, unless you set silent = TRUE
# you'll need to add control flow to keep your loop from breaking at the next function, however
if (class(recall_html) == 'try-error') {
  next
 } else {
  prefecture <- recall_html %>%
        html_nodes(xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "column_ttl_small", " " ))]') %>%
        html_text()
```

Comment: I appreciate your helpful comment. Although I tried the third solution using class(recall_html) == 'try-error', it came out an error like: In if (class(recall_html) == "try-error") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. Would you kindly tell me how should I cope with this warning?

Comment: Oops, replace `tryCatch()` with `try()`

Comment: Please let me know if this updated solution meets your needs, and if so, vote to accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I could solve the problem thanks to your help! Thank you very much.